# Logging of sent/received emails within a web application

Tags: logging, email

We're finally migrating our client/server system to the cloud and would appreciate help on the handling of email within the webapp. Currently we monitor the inbox/sent items of Outlook.

It seems that that some people use a bcc to an app-specific mailbox for the user that can then be logged when sending to a customer, supplier or whatever. (Perhaps also using pairing, multiple "+" within the bcc).

That seems good for sending but I'm unclear how the replies will be received and logged by the webapp. Apparently multiple reply-to values are allowed - is this the way you track them or are there other techniques.

Additionally, if the user is within the UI of the webapp then certain things are possible but what additional steps are necessary if the user is using another device yet needs the webapp to log inbound/outbound emails? Is he/she to manually add the bcc? Thanks in advance

Comment: is this a custom webapp you're creating or some Outlook thing?

Comment: it's a webapp for a vertical market.
Fair-sized crm element at its base

Comment: then just log the details that it sends yourself, or add a bcc to every sent email. I think you need Exchange admin support here, which is offtopic. Serverfault might be a better place to ask.

Comment: It's not at all Exchange specific, it's more about best practices/techniques. The bcc will be a good generic way to handle the logging of the mails (without time pressure) in the background. It means that other email clients used elsewhere by the user may be able to use the same method.  

The biggest question is concerning the replies. Anybody using multiple reply-to's for this? If an email is replied to auser@company.com how can we route this to an application-specific mailbox for the user? Do people set up forwards for every user?

Comment: surely others must have had to deal with this problem, can someone reply please